# ASN1 formatted public key for CryptVerifyMessageSignatureWithKey?

Tags: cryptoapi, asn.1

I´m trying to build a Sign/Decode pair of functions using Cripto API in C++.

The signing process seems to be ok, but I am having a problem getting the decode part to work.
Since I am not relying on certificates, I am using CryptSignMessageWithKey and CryptVerifyMessageSignatureWithKey. The call to CryptVerifyMessageSignatureWithKey, however, is returning a CRYPT_E_ASN1_BADTAG error. Looking for the problem on internet I found one or two discussions on similar topics, but I could not gather some solution from them.

All my code is Crypto API-based. The relevant (I think) parts of it are:

```
CryptAcquireContext(&hCryptProv, cryptContainerName, MS_ENHANCED_PROV, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0);

...

CryptGetUserKey(hCryptProv, AT_SIGNATURE, &hKey);

...

CryptExportKey(hKey, NULL, PUBLICKEYBLOB, 0, pbKeyBlob, &dwKeyBlobLen);

...

sigParams.cbSize = sizeof(CRYPT_KEY_VERIFY_MESSAGE_PARA);
sigParams.dwMsgEncodingType = (PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING | X509_ASN_ENCODING);
sigParams.hCryptProv = NULL;

publicKeyInfo.Algorithm.pszObjId = szOID_RSA_RC4;
publicKeyInfo.Algorithm.Parameters.cbData = 0;
publicKeyInfo.Algorithm.Parameters.pbData = NULL;
publicKeyInfo.PublicKey.pbData = pbKeyBlob;
publicKeyInfo.PublicKey.cbData = dwKeyBlobLen;
publicKeyInfo.PublicKey.cUnusedBits = 0;

...

// ***** ERROR: CRYPT_E_ASN1_BADTAG
CryptVerifyMessageSignatureWithKey(&sigParams, &publicKeyInfo, pbBuffer, dwCount, decodedBlob, &dwCount);
```

Should I transform somehow the public key I got from CryptExportKey to ASN1, and store it in publicKeyInfo.PublicKey.pbData? If it is so, how do I do that?

What is the point I am missing here?

regards, and thanks in advance,
Dan

Comment: Hi all. Problem solved by preparing CERT_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO with CryptExportPublicKeyInfo, as suggested by Andrew7Webb in [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssecurity/thread/b4d1eb0e-d4c1-46f0-80f4-8110a0e26be9](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssecurity/thread/b4d1eb0e-d4c1-46f0-80f4-8110a0e26be9).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by preparing `CERT_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO` with `CryptExportPublicKeyInfo`, as suggested by Andrew7Webb in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssecurity/thread/b4d1eb0e-d4c1-46f0-80f4-8110a0e26be9.